# Fetch refcursor in pl/proxy

Tags: postgresql, cursor, plpgsql, ref-cursor

I am using Postgresql and have the simple function that will return a refcursor to the client:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION select_user(cur refcursor, m_id text)
RETURNS setof refcursor AS $$ 
BEGIN
    OPEN $1 FOR SELECT * FROM public.users WHERE id=m_id;
    RETURN NEXT $1;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

I could fetch the data like this:

```
SELECT select_user('cur','999999'); FETCH ALL in cur;
```

Return 1 Row like this:

```
username   email                id
999999     999999@somewhere.cm  999999
```

But the problem now, I'm using pl/proxy with Postgresql 
In pl/proxy server I wrote this function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION select_user(cur refcursor, m_type integer, m_hid text)
RETURNS setof refcursor AS $$ 
   CLUSTER 'sqlcluster';
   RUN ON select_db(m_hid);
$$ LANGUAGE plproxy;
```

From the above function it return refcursor, but I couldn't fetch the refcursor
Using this command:

```
SELECT select_user('cur','999999'); FETCH ALL in cur;
```

Return error:

```
SQL error:

ERROR:  cursor "cur" does not exist
```

Could anyone explain what's the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The PL/Proxy function is running in a different database, and the refcursor is not  valid there.  You are going to have to redesign that part of the code.

Comment: Could you suggest the best way to select the data? Thanks.

Comment: The use of cursors doesn't make much sense anyway when you are pushing your data through a proxy instance.  I suggest you just return `SETOF some_composite_type`.